# Problem ReCreating Access report in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, crystal-reports

I'm trying to recreate an access report as a crystal report and I'm having trouble.

Basically, the Access report runs a stored procedure (which returns nothing, but populates tables), then those tables are queried to display the data on the report.

So I'm trying to figure out how to run the procedure with parameters from a crystal report. I've got the second part fine, if I run the procedure manually, then display the report I get the appropriate data.

How can I execute the stored procedure before querying those tables from Crystal Reports???

Comment: @MAW74656 ~ We (the mods here) feel this question would be better suited on StackOverflow rather than here on dba. I am a member of both sites, so if you feel that you're not getting the response over there you need, let me know by @ing me and I'll see what can be done. But this is really a programming question more than a dba question.

Comment: What version of Crystal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried combining the stored procedure and the queries into one stored procedure?  Execute the one that populates the tables, and then run the queries that return the data?

Comment: No, my problem is that I actually have 2 sets of data to return.  So I have a query that populates, then I have 2 other selects on the tables that are populated.  I'm not sure what advantage this approach would have?

Comment: You said you were having a problem running the first stored procedure.  If you can't get it to run by itself, you can combine the stored procedure and the first query so that the stored procedure executes, then the query fires and returns the first set of data.  Then run the second query as you currently are, since that's working.

Comment: Now I'm getting the proper data, but the query is taking a looooonnng time to execute.  When I run the equivalent Access report I get results in < 4 seconds.  This takes a minute and a half.  Any thoughts on that quirk?

Comment: I would check and see what part is holding it up.  If you run each part manually, do they run quickly?  Does the stored procedure take longer?  Does one of the queries that returns data take longer?  It's possible you need to create some indexes so that one (or all) of the SQL statements run faster.

Comment: Ok, now I found it: I was executing a different procedure which does almost the same thing.  The names are close and it returns the same information, but works with much more data during execution.  Now I've got it working right.  THanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual Studio (Assumes you were using Access, so you may be a Microsoft shop.) to create a form that triggers the stored procedure and then opens the Crystal Report.

This way users don't have to have Crystal Reports installed. Just your app.

Comment: Ultimately I will use a setup like this, but I'm actually using a console app to save the CR to a pdf.

Comment: I think its better practice to keep the report self-contained, but this would definately work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get away with a combined Access & Crystal approach?

1. The Access db prompts the user for parameters and does whatever it needs to get & filter the data from the db.
2. Crystal generates it's report using the Access db as it's source.

This would be like taking the original Access file, deleting *just* the report, and recreating *just* the report in Crystal, using the original Access queries as your source.

Comment: Afraid not.  I need to cut Access out of the equation.